# Salesforce como hacer un lwc padre con 5 hijos

Tags: javascript, apex, salesforce

me gustaria saber como hacer un lwc padre con 5 hijos para un sales process con 5 etapas, cada uno de los hijos corresponde a cada una de las etapas.

Tengo un codigo que es para las etapas pero lo necesito para un lwc, la logica es mas o menos esta:

````
  doInit: function (component, event, helper) {
    helper.callQueryOpp(component, event, helper);
    helper.initTask(component, event, helper);
    component.set("v.Etapa1", $A.get("$Label.c.MX_SB_PS_Etapa1"));
    component.set("v.Etapa2", $A.get("$Label.c.MX_SB_PS_Etapa2"));
    component.set("v.Etapa3", $A.get("$Label.c.MX_SB_PS_Etapa3"));
    component.set("v.Etapa4", $A.get("$Label.c.MX_SB_PS_Etapa4"));
    component.set("v.Etapa5", $A.get("$Label.c.MX_SB_PS_Etapa5"));
  },
  siguiente: function (component, event, helper) {
    let gtFstage = component.get("v.Etapa1");
    let gtTstage = component.get("v.Etapa3");
    let gtFoStage = component.get("v.Etapa4");
    let gtFifStage = component.get("v.Etapa5");
    if (event.getParam("continuar") === true && event.getParam('nextStageName') === gtFstage) {
      helper.validasiguiente(component, event, helper, gtFstage);
      component.set('v.reloaded', true);
    } else if (event.getParam("continuar") === true && event.getParam('nextStageName') === gtTstage) {
      helper.generateTaskInfo(component, event, helper, gtTstage);
      component.set('v.reloaded', true);
    } else if (event.getParam("continuar") === true && event.getParam('nextStageName') === gtFoStage) {
      helper.generateTaskInfo(component, event, helper, gtFoStage);
    } else if (event.getParam("continuar") === true && event.getParam('nextStageName') === gtFifStage) {
      helper.generateTaskInfo(component, event, helper, gtFifStage);
      component.set('v.reloaded2', true);
    } else if (event.getParam("continuar") === false || event.getParam("continuar") === undefined) {
      helper.toastError(component, event, helper, "Error", "Ooops... algo ocurrio", "");
    }
  },```
````